# Betfair API'ing Certificate login using C++ boost SSL Sockets

Tags: c++, ssl, https, boost-asio

Firstly, thanks for coming here. I'm trying to login with betfair using a certificate login using boost's ssl sockets however, once I send my http login POST, I receive the message **CERT_AUTH_REQUIRED**. On the betfair website it says this means "Certificate required or certificate present but could not authenticate with it". 
I am able to connect, handshake and send/receive data. However, I just can't seem to login with my code. I've tested the exact certificates using curl without any problems.

```
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=IE; ST=Leinster; L=Dublin; O=Paddy Power Betfair Public Limi
ted Company; OU=IT Networks; CN=betfair.com
*        start date: Sep 11 05:50:38 2018 GMT
*        expire date: Sep 11 05:59:00 2020 GMT
*        issuer: C=US; O=HydrantID (Avalanche Cloud Corporation); CN=HydrantID S
SL ICA G2
*        SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate c
hain (19), continuing anyway.
> POST /api/certlogin HTTP/1.1
> Host: identitysso-cert.betfair.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
> X-Application: AOxcQMZwVN3jOsLZ4
> Content-Length: 41
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 41 out of 41 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 87
< Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2019 11:09:35 GMT
<
{"sessionToken":"ZFbyo3HeAh07UFTHzhhGjOyQFeX2MKdHHHHtAm2S7FXw=","loginStatus":"SU
CCESS"}* Connection #0 to host identitysso-cert.betfair.com left intact
```

I have further tested these certificates with python code that also works.
My C++ code is below. I've tried sending incorrect passwords which result in the status from server INVALID_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD instead.

```
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12);

// load certificates
ctx.load_verify_file(cert_filename.c_str());
// ctx.use_private_key_file(private_filename.c_str(), boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
ctx.use_rsa_private_key_file(private_filename.c_str(), boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);

mSocket.reset(new boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>(mIoService, ctx));
mSocket->set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
mSocket->set_verify_callback(
    boost::bind(&BetfairSession::VerifyCertificate, this, _1, _2));

tcp::resolver resolver(mIoService);
tcp::resolver::query query("identitysso-cert.betfair.com", port);
tcp::resolver::iterator endpointIter = resolver.resolve(query);
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the client certificate and the CA List.

This:

```
ctx.load_verify_file(cert_filename.c_str());
```

Is loading a list of CA certificates to verify the server certificate against.

You can find a example of this list here:
http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

You also need to setup the certificate to use for the SSL connection, you do this with the "use_certificate_chain_file" method.
e.g.

```
ctx.use_certificate_chain_file(cert_filename.c_str());
```

Comment: +1 Thank you so much !!!! That did the trick. 
I added ctx.use_certificate_chain_file and it worked instantly.:)